# How to change values of a dropdown list when a other dropdown list has changed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, drop-down-menu, acrobat

okay, edit:

these are the facts,

i have **4** drop down lists, **ddl1, ddl2, ddl3** and **ddl4**

now i want to check, if **ddl1**.value is "**deutschsprachige Länder**". **If so**, then i want to **fill ddl3** with the **options from english_opt2** and **fill ddl4** with the **options from english_opt1**.

And when **ddl2**.value is "**englischsprachige Länder**" than i want to **fill ddl3** with the **options from german_opt2** and **fill ddl4** with the **options from german_opt1**.

And if it is possible, i want to auto select the old value / index (just in the new language.)

```
ddl1 = this.getField("DeutschL");
ddl2 = this.getField("EnglischL");
ddl3 = this.getField("Anrede");
ddl4 = this.getField("Andere Gründe");

english_opt1 =   ["Mögliche andere Gründe auswählen!", 
                 "The recipient is no longer working at that company.",
                 "The recipient is on vacation.", "The recipient is on vacation.",
                 "The receiver is sadly passed away.",
                 "The receiver could not be reached by telephone 3 times.",
                 "The door / access / security code is required.",
                 "The specified address is a flea market.",
                 "The specified address is a Christmas market.",
                 "The specified address is fair.",
                 "The specified telephone number does not belong to the receiver.",
                 "The specified telephone number is not assigned.",
                 "The company is currently closed for summer break.",
                 "The company is currently closed for winter break.",
                 "The company no longer exists.",
                 "The company / the store has closed for renovation.",
                 "There are school holidays in Brandenburg.",
                 "There are school holidays in Berlin."];

german_opt1 =   ["Mögliche andere Gründe auswählen!", 
                "Der Empfänger arbeitet nicht mehr bei dieser Firma.", 
                "Der Empfänger ist im Urlaub.",
                "Der Empfänger ist leider verstorben.", 
                "Der Empfänger konnte 3x telefonisch nicht erreicht werden.", 
                "Der Tür/ Zugangs/ Sicherheits Code ist erforderlich.", 
                "Die angegebene Adresse ist ein Flohmarkt.",
                "Die angegebene Adresse ist ein Weihnachtsmarkt.", 
                "Die angegebene Adresse ist eine Messe.", 
                "Die angegebene Telefonnummer gehört nicht zum Empfänger.", 
                "Die angegebene Telefonnummer ist nicht vergeben.", 
                "Die Firma befindet sich in der Sommerpause.",
                "Die Firma befindet sich in der Winterpause.",
                "Die Firma existiert nicht mehr.", 
                "Die Firma / das Geschäft hat wegen Umbau geschlossen.", 
                "Es sind Schulferien in Brandenburg.",
                "Es sind Schulferien in Berlin."];

english_opt2 =   ["Anrede auswählen!",
                 "Ladies and Gentleman",
                 "Mr.",
                 "Mrs.", 
                 "Family",
                 "Employee of"];

german_opt2 =   ["Anrede auswählen!", 
                "Damen und Herren", 
                "Herr", 
                "Frau", 
                "Mitarbeiter der Firma", 
                "Familie"];
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with Adobe Acrobat, yes you can easily do in plain js, I'll show you.

Comment: I'll take a look at your update in an hour or so.

Comment: There is potential for conflict, because in one case, the language strings are set from ddl1, and in the other case from ddl2. What should happen when ddl1 is "deutschsprachige Länder", and ddl2 is "englischsprachige Länder")?

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest and most efficient object-orient way.

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mf70k9pf/)

**//CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var langs = {
    "eng":["one","two","three"],
    "ger":["eins","zwei","drei"]    
};
document.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(document.readyState == "interactive"){
        document.getElementById("drop1").addEventListener("change",updateDrop);
    }
}
function updateDrop(e){
    var drop = document.getElementById("drop2");
    while(drop.firstChild){
        drop.removeChild(drop.firstChild);
    }
    for(var i=0; i < langs[e.target.value].length; i++){
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.value = langs[e.target.value][i];
        opt.innerHTML = langs[e.target.value][i];
        drop.appendChild(opt);
    }       
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="drop1">
        <option selected disabled>Choose Language</option>
        <option value="eng">English</option>
        <option value="ger">German</option>
    </select>
    <select id="drop2"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So far, all posters did (actively) ignore that the question is indeed on how to deal with the issue in a PDF, meaning in Acrobat JavaScript. Therefore, any code sample using HTML may show some points, but won't be usable.

The following function loads the language strings according to the argument, and maintains the current selection (assuming that the default would be English):

```
function langChang(lang)
{
// saving the current selections of fields ddl3 and ddl4
var select3 = this.getField("Anrede").currentValueIndices ;
var select4 = this.getField("Andere Gründe").currentValueIndices ;

// clearing the comboboxes
this.getField("Anrede").clearItems() ;
this.getField("Andere Gründe").clearItems() ;

switch(lang) {
case "en":
// Loading the English language strings
this.getField("Anrede").setItems(english_opt1) ;
this.getField("Andere Gründe").setItems(english_opt2) ;
break ;
case "de":
// Loading the German language strings
this.getField("Anrede").setItems(german_opt1) ;
this.getField("Andere Gründe").setItems(german_opt2) ;
break ;
default:
// We assumed that the English language strings are the default
this.getField("Anrede").setItems(english_opt1) ;
this.getField("Andere Gründe").setItems(english_opt2) ;
}

// restoring the selections
this.getField("Anrede").currentValueIndices = select3 ;
this.getField("Andere Gründe").currentValueIndices = select4 ;

}
```

You would then run the function with the appropriate argument from the Keystroke event in the DeutschL or EnglishL fields. In those two fields, you would set the "commit selected value immediately" option (in the Options tab of the Field Properties dialog).

Note: you may try to not clear the comboboxes; in this case, it could also be unnecessary to save the current selection. This would make the function smaller. But the current function is more reliable.

Note2: this works because the string arrays have equivalent elements for the languages.

Comment: "Actively" ignore... Lmao he change the question, if you even looked at the revisions you would know that

Answer (score -1):

You can use `<select name="language" onchange="changeNumbers()">` and in Javascript add the following code:

```js
function changeNumbers(lang_val) {
  english_nums = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  german_nums = ['eins', 'zwei', 'drei'];

  if (lang_val == 'english') {
    arr = english_nums;
  } else if (lang_val == 'german') {
    arr = german_nums;
  }
  var options_html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    options_html = options_html + '<option value=' + arr[i] + '>' + arr[i] + '</option>';
  }
  document.getElementById('numbers_select').innerHTML = options_html;
}
```

Comment: This works, but mine is flawless and most efficient :)

Comment: It's not good practice just for future to declare `html Element` with `innerHTML` the elements don't actually get initialized in the view of the DOM, they will appear on the screen but won't be visible by the DOM, the proper way would be to `createElement` and then `appendChild`.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     var english  = ["one", "two", "three"];
     var german  = ["eins", "zwei", "drei "];

        $('#language').on('change', function() {
            var options = "";
            var type = this.value ; 
          //alert( this.value ); // or $(this).val()
          if(type=="english"){
               english.forEach(function(entry) {
            options = options + "<option>"+entry+"</option>";
        });
          }else if(type=="german"){
             german.forEach(function(entry) {
            options = options + "<option>"+entry+"</option>";
        });
          }else{
            options="";
          }
        $("#sub_language").html(options);
        });
});

</script>

<select id="language">
   <option value="0" selected>select</option>
    <option value="english">english</option>
    <option value="german">german</option>
</select>
<select id="sub_language">

</select>
```

Comment: is it plain Javascript?

Comment: Yea I see lil jQuery in there.

Answer (score -1):

There is `<div id="box"></div>` which is placed two `select` tags.

Then, other tags will create through JavaScript

```js
var lang = ["english", "german"];
var second = [
    ["one", "two", "second"],
    ["eins", "zwei", "drei "]
];

addOptions(lang, "first");
addOptions(second[0], "second");

function addOptions(arr, selectId) {
    var s = document.getElementById(selectId);
    if (!s) {
        s = document.createElement("select");
        var myDiv = document.getElementById("box");
        myDiv.appendChild(s);

        s.id = selectId;
    }
    s.options.length = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.text = arr[i];
        option.value = arr[i];
        s.options[s.options.length] = option;
    }
}


document.getElementById("first").onchange = function () {
    console.log(this.selectedIndex)
    addOptions(second[this.selectedIndex], "second");
};
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: This works, but mine is flawless and most efficient :)

Comment: :) Ok Jordan(+1). Also, There isn't html code my answer(full plain JS). good luck

Comment: you're welcome. :) it is for efford. I don't think it is more efficient. :)

Comment: Haha :) nah I'm 100% sure mines more efficient, not by much but it is... I am OCD and take adderall and dwell over finding the most efficient ways :D

Comment: Haha the fact that I'm statically declaring HTML on initialization gives me an advantage, as well as my variable declaration count, and the empty spaces you have :) but honestly like I said it's not much difference... your utilizing DOM just as well as I am for the most part, but when you develop in C or Assembly code like I do you deal a lot more with managing memory and worry about these things.

Comment: That funniest thing is I would say 90% of js devs rely on frameworks and actually have no idea how to use javascript that actual language and when they see people like us developing in pure DOM and they have no idea what were doing, its pure comedy to me.

Comment: Hm, maybe. I just answer to question(question demands plain JavaScript)